# Parent ID causing Migration Problems

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I am trying to migrate a SharePoint list from a SharePoint 2013 Server to SharePoint 2013. However I am running into exceptions when trying to import the list.

> Exception: An error occurred during the operation of a service method: The list item could not be inserted or updated because invalid lookup values were found for the following field(s) in the list: [Parent ID].

I am using the standard `Import-SPWeb` and `Export-SPWeb`

In exploring the XML of each item in the list, I noticed there is a `ParentID` field with random numbers. I am not sure what the `ParentID` is or how to get rid of it for the `Import-SPWeb`

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is a version mismatch. The back end schema's in 2010 and 2013 are not same.

The easiest option is

1. Use internet explorer and export the data into Excel
2. Now format the excel file and remove unwanted columns
3. Save it to local folder
4. Open 2013 site and create a new list from the excel file

Another 3 options are explained in this article - https://absolute-sharepoint.com/2013/08/how-to-move-a-list-from-sharepoint-2010-to-sharepoint-2013.html

Comment: Appreciate it Amal, however I was informed wrong for the SP Versions. They are both SP 2013. I tried to move the list to Excel and reimport, but that didn't work. I downloaded a free Third-Party software (up to 25GB) called Metalogix and still getting the Parent ID Exception. Any other ideas?